# Mystery VM Javascript duplicating script calls - where does it come from and how do I kill it?

Tags: javascript, full-page-cache

I have a module which runs properly on my local instance of 1.9.1. On uploading it to a staging server, javascript that I added to the Admin Order page is running twice. After littering the files with comments, output in Chrome Dev tools shows a js file called "VM13876" that, when I click through in dev tools, is a block of js that I wrote inside a file, pulled aside into what looks like external js.

Sample output from dev tools:

```
RETURN Pressed                          (index):2122 
This is productGridAddSelected          sales.js:639
This is beginning of loop               sales.js:646
MADE IT THROUGH LOOP                    sales.js:655
end of productConfigureSubmit           sales.js:853
END OF  productGridAddSelected          sales.js:660 
After productGridAddSelected            (index):2140 
RETURN Pressed                          VM13876:22
This is productGridAddSelected          sales.js:639 
This is beginning of loop               sales.js:646
MADE IT THROUGH LOOP                    sales.js:655 
end of productConfigureSubmit           sales.js:853
END OF  productGridAddSelected          sales.js:660
After productGridAddSelected            VM13876:40
```

Does anyone know what the source of the second, "VM" js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't intended for this to be a self-answered question, but as I was typing I mulled the behavior a bit and..

I thought this may have something to do with caching, so I killed the Mirasvit Full Page Cache extension, and sure enough, the VM javascript calls are gone.

Hopefully someone in the future finds this useful, as it's a bit of an odd error, but if anyone has any pointers on how to run the full page cache without it running custom Javascript twice I would definitely be interested.